# Creating border using box shadow?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a border for my elements using `CSS box shadow`.
However, I can't seem to get this to work.

This is my code:

```css
.vid_img{
display:inline-block; 
width:25%;
vertical-align: top;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 -1px red;

}
```

```html
<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/204611/pexels-photo-204611.jpeg" class="vid_img"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/204611/pexels-photo-204611.jpeg" class="vid_img"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/204611/pexels-photo-204611.jpeg" class="vid_img"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/204611/pexels-photo-204611.jpeg" class="vid_img">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```css
.vid_img {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 25%;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/204611/pexels-photo-204611.jpeg" class="vid_img"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/204611/pexels-photo-204611.jpeg" class="vid_img"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/204611/pexels-photo-204611.jpeg" class="vid_img"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/204611/pexels-photo-204611.jpeg" class="vid_img">
```